# error actualizar label con selectOneMenu java jsf + primfaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Buenas estoy tratando de imprimir en un `label` el nombre al momento de seleccionar un ítem en un `selectOneMenu` pero no me lo captura el menu funciona bien me muestra todas las cedulas disponible en mi tablas así esta definido mi `selectOneMenu`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{cargarArchivo.ticket.chofer}" style="width: 100%" converter="choferConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{cargarArchivo.listCho}" var="tipo" itemLabel="#{tipo.cedula}" itemValue="#{tipo}"/>                
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

y este es el `label` en el que quiero que se muestre.

`<p:outputLabel value="#{cargarArchivo.ticket.chofer.nombre}" />`

Comment: Intentaste haciendo un update al outputlabel?!

Comment: por lo que había investigado el converter realizaba esa función nose si eso sea cierto no tengo idea que tipo de ajax podria usar en este caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigue un poco, de lo que pude encontrar podrías utilizar un evento ajax para que al seleccionar el item dentro del selectOneMenu tu outputLabel cambie:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{cargarArchivo.ticket.chofer}" style="width: 100%" converter="choferConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{cargarArchivo.listCho}" var="tipo" itemLabel="#{tipo.cedula}" itemValue="#{tipo}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="outPut1" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Y a tu outputLabel le asignarias el Id del update en el selectOneMenu:

```
<p:outputLabel id="outPut1" value="#{cargarArchivo.ticket.chofer.nombre}" />
```

Inclusive en el ajax, podrias usar un listener para que lo controles mejor en el bean, algo así:

```
...
<p:ajax event="change" update="outPut1" listener="#{cargarArchivo.metodoTickets}"/>
...
```

Espero te ayude mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: listo implementando ajax funciona correctamente gracias.

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado.